# Tax and Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm having some issues with the tax in the Craft Commerce plugin. All prices typed in the CP are without tax and I need to show the price in the front-end with a 25% tax included. If a product cost 5000 it has to show 6250. The same goes for the cart lineitem. But I can't make it work. What's the correct way for this approach?

Comment: If the product should show 6250 and is entered as 5000 then the tax should not be marked as included. The tax will only up in the cart.

Comment: Yes - that's working fine now. But then I need to do some twigs math in the template. Would have been nice if there was a variable with the price+ tax in the product variant modal as well.

Comment: I need that too. Do you got it working?

Comment: Yes I got that working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part from the 'tax included in price' option within a tax rate, there is no option to include taxes in the price of the item on the front-end. Tax is calculated in the cart.

If you wish to add the tax to the product's price before the cart, you would need to do so in twig/plugin yourself.